# Multer to manage different file names in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I did a code to store files in-memory storage and pass it to email attachment and storing them in Cloud storage. Initially, I was trying to receive the image file in the name 'image'.

```
const multer = require('multer');
const inMemoryStorage = multer.memoryStorage();

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
      if (
        file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg')
       {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
      }
    };

app.use(
      multer({ storage: inMemoryStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image'));
```

It was working fine. I am able to get the file data in `req.file`.

Now I am trying to change the code to manage to receive the files in a different name. Did some changes in fileFilter and multer constructor by referring to some questions available in the forum as below.

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (
      file.fieldname === 'files' && (
        file.mimetype === 'application/pdf' ||
        file.mimetype === 'application/msword' ||
        file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else if (
      file.fieldname === 'image' && (
      file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
      file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
      file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg')
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
    }
  };


app.use(
    multer({ storage: inMemoryStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).fields([
      {
        name:'image'
      },
      {
        name:'files'
      }
    ])
  )
```

I expected to receive the file from `req.file`. But I am getting `undefined` at the end. I don't know how to Identify the issue here. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You were using `multer.single`, which handles a *single* file, and stores its data in `req.file` (singular).

You're now using `multer.fields`, which can handle multiple files, and stores their respective data in `req.files` (plural).

Check out the `.single`, `.array` and `.fields` examples in the first code block of the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Side note: same will happen with `.any`, as per the same doc:

> Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in `req.files`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support different names you can do this:

```
app.use(multer({ storage: inMemoryStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).any())
```